# Is there a general theorem for lines intersecting in $R^2_{++}$ space?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Im wondering if there is a general theorem which discusses whether or not two lines that intersect in the  $\mathbb{R}_{++}^2$. This is visualized in the graph below.
[image]

If there is a broader theorem discussing if multiple lines intersecting in this space or in higher dimensions in terms of planes that would be useful as well.

Does such a theorem exist?

Comment: The region you ask about might also be called the first quadrant of the Cartesian plane.  If we want to limit it to *strictly positive* coordinates, then we could say the *interior* of the first quadrant.

Comment: @hardmath thank you for the terminology!

Comment: In the end people will denote $(0,\infty)^n$ by ${\mathbb R}^n_{(+)^n}$.

Comment: The picture illustrates a sufficient condition in terms of intercepts that implies an intersection of the kind you want.  If both lines have positive $x-$ and $y-$intercepts, say $x_A,y_A \gt 0$ for line $A$ and similarly for line $B$, then $(x_A-x_B)(y_A-y_B)\lt 0$ implies the point of intersection exists with positive coordinates.

Comment: @hardmath Thats a pretty well written result, Formalize the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Sure, let me think about the case of planes in three dimensions over night.